# How to close Bootstrap 5 modal in React.js?

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-5, bootstrap5-modal

Using [Bootstrap 5 Modal](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/) in React.js, the Modal opens on click of the button. If we have a form on the modal, need to perform some validations, and allow to submit the form on successful validation - we cannot use `data-bs-dismiss="modal"` to submit button, as it closes the modal immediately.

Now, what is the best approach to close the modal on successful form submission?

Please provide a solution without using jQuery as it is removed from Bootstrap v5 and also not recommended to use alongside React.js.

Also, many have suggested NOT to use document.getElementByID or document.querySelector in React because of its Virtual DOM usage concept.

**Update:** Able to achieve it with a workaround solution by clicking the Close button after successful form submission, as shown below. But still looking for an ideal solution, if there is any.

In constructor, created a ref:

```
this.closeModalRef = React.createRef();
```

In render, added this ref for close button:

```
<button type="button" className="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal" id='closeModal' ref={this.closeModalRef}>Close</button>
```

In submit handler, after successful form submission:

```
this.closeModalRef.current.click();
```

Comment: Doesn't Bootstrap use classes to animate elements? If so, you could hook into the success callback and remove the class from the modal.

Comment: Can you instead just use something like react-bootstrap that provides components specifically made to work with react and support capabilities like open/close with data attributes?

Comment: Please see [ask]. You need to show some code so we have something specific to discuss.

Comment: https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/modal/#modals-live

Comment: @JoelHager Do you have any sample code to achieve it with React?

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky react-bootstrap is not yet supporting Bootstrap 5. I'm trying out with plain Bootstrap 5.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, non-react Bootstrap targets DOM elements via data attributes. React  sits *before* it's rendered, so in order to target the actual DOM elements, you'd have to pass refs, if I'm not mistaken. Seems like a giant PITA to me...

Comment: @JoelHager where are you seeing the need for ref in the react bootstrap modal documentation?

Answer (score 1):

you can also try

```
document.getElementById('closeModal').click();
```